# cropping image in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, crop

windows phone 8 using visual studio
I'm trying to crop an image to 81 piece  after i captured it through mobile cam but i found this exception. any help??

```
int halfWidth = (App.CroppedImage.PixelWidth / 9);
int halfHeight =(App.CroppedImage.PixelHeight / 9);
for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
    {
        WriteableBitmap wr = App.CroppedImage.Crop(col * halfHeight, row * halfWidth, halfWidth, halfHeight);
        MediaLibrary MLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
        IsolatedStorageFileStream IsoStoreFileStreams = myStore.CreateFile("test"+row+col+".jpg");
        Extensions.SaveJpeg(wr, IsoStoreFileStreams, 100, 100, 0, 85);
        IsoStoreFileStreams.Close();
        IsoStoreFileStreams = myStore.OpenFile("test"+ row + col +".jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        //Add the JPEG file to the photos library on the device.
        MediaLibrary libraryy = new MediaLibrary();
        Picture picc = library.SavePicture("Saved"+row+col+".jpg", IsoStoreFileStreams);
        IsoStoreFileStreams.Close();
    }
```

the exception in this function 
`Extensions.SaveJpeg(wr, IsoStoreFileStreams, 100, 100, 0, 85);`
and the message is

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: What is this "`Extensions`" class? Do You have the code for it?

Comment: I installed it from NuGet

Comment: What is the name of the NuGet package?

Comment: WritableBitMapExtension & thanks for your concern Ialready solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

stack 
sorry i found my error it was `
        WriteableBitmap wr = App.CroppedImage.Crop(col * halfWidth, row * halfHeight, halfWidth, halfHeight);

instead

WriteableBitmap wr = App.CroppedImage.Crop(col * halfHeight, row * halfWidth, halfWidth, halfHeight);

`